# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ convergent for all bounded sequences $b_n$, Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

I have seen previous questions about this sort of question (assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converge and $b_n$ bounded $\rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_nb_n|$).
But I can't find the answer for this question , perhaps I'm missing something.

I know that $\forall n : |b_n|<M$ for some $M>0$ so $|a_nb_n|\le M|a_n|$
but it doesn't suffice the comparison test since I need to find the inverse inequality symbol $\ge$ and because we don't know if $|a_nb_n|$ converge , only $a_nb_n$ converge for our knowledge.
if we take $b_n = (-1)^n$ then we get that $a_n$ converge by the criteria that $b_n$ is bounded and $a_nb_n$ is convergent.

I'm not sure what else to understand from the meaning of $a_nb_n$ convergent series...

Comment: Is there some bounded sequence $b_n$ such that $a_nb_n = |a_n|$??????????

Comment: $b_n=\operatorname{sign}(a_n)$ wil do.

Comment: $b_n=sgn a_n$.........

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kb_k$ converges for every bounded sequence {$b_k$}, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges absolutely.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173591/sum-k-1-inftya-kb-k-converges-for-every-bounded-sequence-b-k-prove) – Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20a_nb_n%24%2C%20%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%7Ca_n%7C%24%2C%20bounded&p=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let$$b_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }a_n\geqslant0\\-1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges. In other words, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|$ converges.

Comment: hmm it's even simpler than I though , Great answer , I will accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Or $b_n=e^{-it}$ for $a_n=re^{it}$.